# Dropdown menu does not align right

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I have a dropdown menu button that shows only when the screen is too small. I need to align it to the right, but `float:right;` doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/VZ9y8/

Here's the CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;

}
#cssmenu {
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #fefefe;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #eee9f0));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  display:block;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #fefefe;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #ececec));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Stile con freccia bassa  
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
  */
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Stile con freccia bassa  
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
  */
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #ececec;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #ececec;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 2;




}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;


}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
```

The alignment works only if I add `right:-50px` but it's not a safe solution.

Comment: What do you mean that it only works with `right:-50px`? I don't see anything strange. The dropdown is exactly below the button.

Comment: @putvande is not the dropdown the problem is the li parent of it.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Next time put that in the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this two properties:

```
.#cssmenu > ul {
    width:100%;
}
```

When your `ul` is the 100% of the screen then the `float:right` works

```
#cssmenu .has-sub {
   float:right;
}
```

See your code here http://jsfiddle.net/VZ9y8/3/